# Awk in Shell Script Error: Unexpected End of File

Tags: shell, awk

I received an error stating: "line 32 (final line): syntax error: unexpected end of file". I couldn't find the source of the error.

First input for the script: Input file name

Second input for the script: Employee name

Second column of the input file: Employee name

Fifth column of the input file: Salary

Sixth column of the input file: Date of joining

---

Below is my script:

```
# Check whether or not the command has two arguments

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then

   echo "You must enter 2 arguments!\n"

   echo "Application is now exiting..."

   exit

fi



# Check whether or not the employee name supplied by the user is available in the input file

awk -v employee_name=$2 -v is_employee_available=0 -v year=0 -v new_salary=0 

'BEGIN{FS="|"}

{

   if(employee_name == $2) {

      is_employee_available=1;

      year=strtonum(substr($6,8,11));

      if(year==1990) 

         new_salary=$5+2000;     

      else if(year==1991) 

         new_salary=$5+1500; 

      else if(year==1992) 

         new_salary=$5+1000; 

      else if(year>1992) 

         new_salary=$5+500;   

      else 

         print "Invalid year of joining!";    

   }

}

END

{ 

   if(is_employee_available==0)

      print "The provided employee does not exist!"; 

}' $1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily relevant, but the `$1` and `$2` should be quoted in the shell script parts. Also, I think the quoted script part should start on the same line as `awk`.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, thank you for advising me the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v employee_name=$2 -v is_employee_available=0 -v year=0 -v new_salary=0 

'BEGIN{FS="|"}
^
Because of this
```

**To**

```
awk -v employee_name="$2" -v is_employee_available="0" -v year="0" -v new_salary="0" '
BEGIN{FS="|"}
```

**OR**

```
awk -v employee_name="$2" -v is_employee_available="0" -v year="0" -v new_salary="0" \
\
'BEGIN{FS="|"}
```

> **and**
>
> (with this you will get : END blocks must have an action part)

END

```
{
```

**To**

```
END{
```

**OR**

```
END\
\
{
```

> **and** ( quoting is good practice )

```
}' $1
```

**To**

```
}' "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem. I really appreciate your effort.